# Javascript - Converting a String to an Array and Back Again within Chained Map Methods

Tags: javascript, arrays

Goal: I am trying to chain .map() methods together with a string to array conversion and then back to a string [currently via .split(" ") and .join("")] .

Context: The challenge asks to convert a string of binary numbers into text (please note, this is not what I am asking help on).

My answer (which works):

```
function binaryAgent(str) {
  let arr = str.split(" ");
  //METHOD TWO -  Chaining the commands together
  arr.map((k,index) => {
    arr.unshift(parseInt(k,2));
    arr.splice(index+1,1);    
  }).map((k,index) => {
    arr.unshift(String.fromCharCode(arr[index]));
    arr.splice(index+1,1);
  })
  let string = arr.join("");
  return string;
}
binaryAgent("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000");
```

The Work (Which I want to understand if there is a way to get it to work which I am missing):

```
function binaryAgent(arr) {

  //METHOD TWO -  Chaining the commands together
  let string = arr.split(" ").map((k,index) => {
    arr.unshift(parseInt(k,2));
    arr.splice(index+1,1);    
  }).map((k,index) => {
    arr.unshift(String.fromCharCode(arr[index]));
    arr.splice(index+1,1);
  }).join("");

  return string;
}
binaryAgent("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000");
```

The second bit of code is returning an "arr.unshift is not a function" error. As if the original string has not been converted to an array, even though, if written on it's own line it would. I.E. 
`arr = arr.split(" ")` works just fine and converts the string to an array.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your mapping functions aren't returning anything meaning you'll have an array of `undefined` values after the first `map()`. If that's intentional, it would be better to use `forEach()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Array.map()` method iterates an array, creates a new array, and applies a callback function to each item. Whatever the callback function returns is the item's value in the new array.

You are using map to iterate the array, but you're mutating the original array, and don't return anything from the callback (implicitly return `undefined`).

In the callback transform `k` (the item) and return it:

```js
function binaryAgent(str) {
  return str.split(" ")
    .map(k => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(k, 2)))
    .join("");
}

const result = binaryAgent("01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000");

console.log(result);
```